# '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help with Python3, please

I've got a simple code, which turns the even minimum of the list into the string

```
source_array = [5,2,3,7]
i = 0
    
while min(source_array) % 2 == 0:
    i = source_array.index(min(source_array))
    source_array[i] = str(source_array[i])
```

it gives me an error: `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

I'd think, that it's just a language feature, but such code works perfectly:

```
b = [5,2,3,7]
b[1] = str(b[1])
print(b)
```

```
Output:
[5, '2', 3, 7]
```

what is the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: At the second iteration of your loop, the `min` tries to compare the element, and it can't compare with the ints and the one that have bacome an string

Comment: Python does not know how to compare ints and strings. And it does compare them inside `min(source_array)` call.

Comment: Did you mean: `if min(source_array) % 2 == 0:`?

Comment: the issue exist in this line `source_array[i] = str(source_array[i])` which turns integer list into a list of ints and strings, and you can't apply max/min on such lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works quite ok:

```
source_array = [5,2,3,7]
i = 0
    
if min(source_array) % 2 == 0:
    i = source_array.index(min(source_array))
    source_array[i] = str(source_array[i])
print(source_array)
```

The problem is in the loop, the second time it goes in the `while`, it is comparing string and int and it does not like it.

Answer (score 2):

You must eliminate not `int` values to get minimum. You can use `lambda` function to get a new list only contains `int` values

```py
source_array = [5,2,3,7]
i = 0
    
while min(list(filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, source_array))) % 2 == 0:
    i = source_array.index(min(source_array))
    source_array[i] = str(source_array[i])

print(source_array)
```

Output

```
[5, '2', 3, 7]
```

### Edit:

I have checked if there are 4 number without 3. The algorithm is not working again. I have to define `filter` and `lambda` expressions into `source_array.index(...)`. However, I don't like to define the same command more than once. Maybe you can use a variable for a temporary list.

**Note** if all numbers are even, you will get another error, you should check are there any items as int?

```py
source_array = [5,2,4,7]
i = 0
    
while min(list(filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, source_array))) % 2 == 0:
    i = source_array.index(min(list(filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, source_array))))
    source_array[i] = str(source_array[i])

print(source_array)
```

Output:

```
[5, '2', '4', 7]
```

More even numbers and a single odd number.

```py
source_array = [12, 4, 8, 6, 15]

['12', '4', '8', '6', 15]
```